# calling .exe from another .exe to run a webservice

Tags: c#, cmd

i have tried with several type of examples to call a .exe file from another .exe file with parameters to
run a 'web service',but i am getting some times '500 – Internal Server Error  exception'.

```
1. code in First .Exe(code for only for one event, i have 8 event like this to run in Button click)    

    dateTimePicker4.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";   
            string frodate = dateTimePicker4.Value.Date.ToShortDateString();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = @"C:\WebserviceClient.exe";           // this is the second .EXE file
            startInfo.Arguments = "300000 supplier" + " " + frodate;   // thesse are the 3 parameters
            Process.Start(startInfo);

 2. My second .Exe file receive these parameters and call the Web-Service like below

WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://My Server Path/epos/getproduct.asmx"); // this is web service in another location 
            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequest;
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/getCategory");
            httpRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            httpRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
            //Create Stream and Complete Request             
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.ASCII);

        StringBuilder soapRequest = new StringBuilder("<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"");
        soapRequest.Append(" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" ");
        soapRequest.Append("xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body>");
        soapRequest.Append("<getCategory xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">");
        soapRequest.Append("<inBranch>" + strParam + "</inBranch>");
        soapRequest.Append("<dir>" + strParamDir + "</dir>");
        soapRequest.Append("<modifyDateFrom>" + strModifyDateFrom + "</modifyDateFrom>");
        soapRequest.Append("<modifyDateTo>" + strModifyDateTo + "</modifyDateTo>");
        soapRequest.Append("</getCategory>");

        soapRequest.Append("</soap:Body></soap:Envelope>");

        streamWriter.Write(soapRequest.ToString());
        streamWriter.Close();
        //Get the Response    
        HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();  // here i am getting the ERROR
        StreamReader srd = new StreamReader(wr.GetResponseStream());
        string resulXmlFromWebService = srd.ReadToEnd();
```

// NOTE-- i have to run this service 8 times with different parameters, when i call this second .EXE from 8 batch files one by one, then no issue.

now i am trying to Run this service from my First .Exe instad of Batch file one by one in button click events , then i am getting the 500 error when first event complete second event start.

what i am doing wrong,Please give me some suggestions.

Comment: Try adding "Process.WaitForExit();" after your Process.Start(startInfo);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\WebserviceClient.exe";
```

with this line:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { Process.Start("C:\\WebserviceClient.exe"); });
```

**Another way is the following:**

```
    public static void TestCommands()
    {
        var command = "WebserviceClient.exe";
        ExecuteCommand(command, 5000);
        var command = "WebserviceClient2.exe";
        ExecuteCommand(command, 5000);
    }

    public static int ExecuteCommand(string command, int timeout)
    {
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command)
        {
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            WorkingDirectory = @"C:\\",
        };

        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
        process.WaitForExit(timeout);
        var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
        process.Close();
        return exitCode;
    }
```

Comment: oh,Yes. Little bit doubt, seems this process not ending in single process, running 3 times. i am not sure exactly, i am testing my application, 2 time i got same results(as executed 3 times). still testing, any way thanks for solution.

Comment: Hi all, my system is working good. the problem is, when i run the service all the related records are inserting in my log table,but after some time, the records are inserting second time also, and it is continuously inserting duplicate records in my log table. how can i stop this duplicate inserting.Advice me

Comment: I'd suggest posting another question with the details.