# WebService not running exe

Tags: vb.net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, exe

I have referenced a few mentions of how to do this on stackoverflow.

I tried testing from the following reference code :

https://www.dotnetperls.com/process

[How to run .exe file by my Webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936631/how-to-run-exe-file-by-my-webservice)

VERSION: Framework 3.5

VisualStudio2010

When i ran my code below in the browser, I see the bullet point to click on. When I click on it nothing happens. My exe simply locates an xml file and creates a new file from it. I want to use a webservice to run the exe. Is there something I am missing in my code? There are other versions I saw that had more code but I tried them and still had no luck [check my link]

This is my first webservice so I am learning as I go.

```
Imports System.Web.Services
Imports System.Web.Services.Protocols
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO

' To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
' <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://localhost/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class Service1
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

Dim File As String

<WebMethod()> _
Public Sub runExe()

Dim exe = "C:\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsApplication1.exe"
    'Dim file = "C:\Test\test.xml"

    Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
    startInfo.FileName = exe
    'startInfo.Arguments = file
    Process.Start(startInfo)

    'REFERENCE: https://www.dotnetperls.com/process

End Sub
```

I also tried [calling .exe from another .exe to run a webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26029909/calling-exe-from-another-exe-to-run-a-webservice) by using

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Sub() Process.Start("C:\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsApplication1.exe"))
```

but the exe didn't run aka I didn't see the new file created in the folder path the exe sends it to.

also tried:

```
Dim processInfo = New ProcessStartInfo(exe)
Dim process__1 = Process.Start(ProcessInfo)
process__1.WaitForExit(5000)
Dim exitCode = process__1.ExitCode
process__1.Close()
Return
```

nothing happened

**UPDATE:**

Didn't think to use a output test to find my issue. I used the following:

```
While Not process__1.StandardOutput.EndOfStream
   Dim line As String = process__1.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
End While
```

Comment: `WindowsApplication1.vshost.exe`?  Don't you mean to run `WindowsApplication1.exe`?  Also, can you do some debugging to confirm that the application isn't being executed?  Maybe include some debugging output in the application?  Or read the output from the process when you invoke it here?  It seems likely that it's either failing for a good reason that you just aren't capturing or your test isn't doing what you think it does.

Comment: yes that was typo. I will look into creating an output of the process. @David

Comment: Also, while this may be obvious, it's often worth asking because a lot of people get hung up on this... Are you expecting this application to run on the *server* or on the *client*?

Comment: well I'm planning to use my asp.net application to communicate with this service to run exe. so I would think client... @David

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment...

> well I'm planning to use my asp.net application to communicate with this service to run exe. so I would think client

That's an incorrect understanding of how web applications work.  Your server-side ASP.NET code (the VB parts) are just that, *server-side*.  All of that code executes on the web server.  The browser/client/etc. has no knowledge of it.

(Imagine for a moment a world where any website you visit could arbitrarily execute any .NET code they want on your computer.  Doesn't sound like fun.)

If you want the *client* to execute an application, you have to send the application to the client (such as a link to download it) and basically ask them to run it.  Your server-side code can't automatically execute applications on the client's computer.

Comment: wouldn't that mean webservices would usually be serverside then if used by an application?

Comment: I also used the following test code `While Not process__1.StandardOutput.EndOfStream
            ' do something with line
            Dim line As String = process__1.StandardOutput.ReadLine()
        End While` and it did in fact determine I was mapping to wrong location. I saved my new location but didn't rebuild in that new location which was my issue.

Comment: @narue1992: Web services are server-side.  The name even implies it.  It's a service exposed over the web.  It seems like you may have some fundamental misconceptions of how web applications work.